# Why fetch from React Native to Nginx + Phusion Passenger + Rails 5 with devise-token-auth, just response 401?

Tags: react-native, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, devise-token-auth

I could configure an Nginx-Passenger-Rails5 and deploy with Capistrano with this tutorial https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04#nginx-passenger for my API. After trying with Postman and httpie seems to work, the only problem is that I have an App on React Native and fetch stop working, just show 401 Unauthorized.

I already try to add Cors to Nginx and rails (application.rb) reading in other places, but still not working.

Some of my code

```
server {

  client_body_in_file_only on;

  server_name api.my.server.name www.api.my.server.name;
  root /home/deploy/funes-api/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name myapp_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
    ignore_invalid_headers off;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" 'access-token,client,expiry,uid,token-type,Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,access-token,client,expiry,uid,token-type';

#    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.funes.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.funes.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.my.server.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.my.server.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'access-token,client-expiry,uid,token-type,Content-Type';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';

  server_name api.my.server.name www.my.server.name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
          headers: :any,
          expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
          methods: [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
      end
    end
```

The response every time just shows 401 Unauthorized